# What is the format of Kafka's adminClient properties file which is used with argument "--command-config"?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using `kafka-console-producer.sh` like this:

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server $BTSTRP --topic test --producer.config client.properties
```

and it works great without warnings or errors. In `client.properties` I have some properties. Part of the example file:

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

---

Then I would like to use below command to list SCRAM users using the same `client.properties` because it matches [everything here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#adminclientconfigs):

```
kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server $BTSTRP --command-config client.properties --describe --entity-type users
```

but it prints below warnings (not a full output) and eventually does not work (prints nothing but these warnings):

```
[2020-09-24 10:30:27,823] WARN The configuration 'ssl.keystore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2020-09-24 10:30:27,823] WARN The configuration 'ssl.keystore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2020-09-24 10:30:27,823] WARN The configuration 'ssl.truststore.password' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2020-09-24 10:30:27,823] WARN The configuration 'ssl.truststore.password' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2020-09-24 10:30:27,823] WARN The configuration 'ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2020-09-24 10:30:27,823] WARN The configuration 'ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
```

---

**Question**: How am I supposed to format Kafka's Admin client `--command-config` properties file? I've already read through here, but nothing seem to help:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-248+-+Create+New+ConfigCommand+That+Uses+The+New+AdminClient
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-377%3A+TopicCommand+to+use+AdminClient
- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#adminclientconfigs

Comment: Did you find a find a fix for this, I have same issue?

Comment: Yes. Update Kafka to a new version and warnings will go away.